# UNIX: Difference xargs and exec

Tags: exec, xargs

I am trying to search for the string `"rGEO"` in a directory by using the following commands:

```
find . -name "*" -type f -print | xargs grep "rGEO" 
./home/oper1/AgencyTape/geo/exe/gngeo.cmd:${WEB_DIR}/exe/web_reports.sh -aGN -d${prev_ccyy}${prev_mm} -rGEO -nomail
```

In this case, I get back the file name which has the matching line, as well as the line which matches the above string.

```
find . -name "*" -type f -exec grep "rGEO" {} \;
```

In this case, I get back:

```
${WEB_DIR}/exe/web_reports.sh -aGN -d${prev_ccyy}${prev_mm} -rGEO -nomail
```

The file which contains the line isn't printed - and, as you can see, there is a lot of difference between the two outputs.

Using `xargs` gives more clear and precise output.

My question is: what is the difference between the two commands? To me, they seem to be performing the same logic, but getting different results.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of [Which is faster, 'find -exec' or 'find | xargs -0'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980411/which-is-faster-find-exec-or-find-xargs-0) since this asks about the differences and that question asks about which is faster, but the difference is that `xargs` invokes the command in batches while `find -exec` invokes the command once per result, which makes `xargs` faster.

Comment: More to the point:  `find -exec` is pretty much identical to `find -print0 |xargs -0n1` since `-n1` ensures one call per result.

Answer (score 6):

*`what is the difference between the two commands? To me, they seem to be performing the same logic, but getting different results.`*

Below is one major difference between xargs and exec:

`find . -name "*.c" -exec ls -al {} \;` executes the command ls -al on each individual file.

`find . -name "*.c" | xargs ls -al` constructs an argument list from the output of the find command and passes it to ls.

consider the below produced output of the find command:

```
a.c
b.c
c.c
```

the first command(exec) would execute

```
ls -l a.c
ls -l b.c
ls -l c.c
```

but the second (xargs) would execute

```
ls -l a.c b.c c.c
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Adding -print will return the name of the file also, although in all little different way.

```
find . -name "*" -type f -exec grep "rGEO" {} \; -print
```

I am not aware of the internal working, here is how it differs.
Suppose find commands finds 2 files a.txt and b.txt

-exec will work on them like.

```
grep "rGEO" a.txt
grep "rGEO" b.txt
```

however xargs will work like..

```
grep "rGEO" a.txt b.txt.
```

Hope it helps